# I am getting NoMethodError in Books#add in my ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am extremely new to Ruby, just started learning about 4 weeks ago. I am just building something very small at the moment. A form with some fields that stores the data input about a book title and then spits it out in a list underneath for form so far this is what I have got:

```
books_controller.rb

    class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def add
    @book_name = params[:book_name]
  end

  def sign_in
        @book_name = params[:book_name]
    unless @book_name.blank?
        @book = Book.create({:book_name => @book_name})
    end
        @books = Book.all
  end
end
```

This is where the controller is created. Pretty straight forward I think.

This is the database creater thing here:

```
class CreateBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :books do |t|
      t.string :book_name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Then we have app/models/book.rb:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :book_name
end
```

Then I have an add template where the book name is added and the list is created(this is the page I get my error on)

```
<p>Find me in app/views/books/add.html.erb</p>

<h2>Recent book: <%= @book_name %> and the Author is: <%= @book_author %></h2>
<%= form_tag :action => 'add' do %>
<p>Book name: <%= text_field_tag 'book_name', @book_name %></p>
<%= submit_tag 'Add Book' %>
<% end %>

<p>Book list:</p>
<ul>
<% @books.each do |book| %>
<li><%= book.book_name %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
<hr>
<%= debug(params) %>
<%= debug(assigns) %>
```

Would anyone happen to know why I get this error, I will show the full error below:

NoMethodError in Books#add
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Any help would be great on this.

Cheers,
Mark

Comment: In your controller for the "add" method, you should also add `@books.all`. I guess "add" is your "new" method and "sign_in" as you "create" method.

Comment: Yeah, thats right. So in my books_controller.rb I should put @books.all as a new instance variable with = params[:books] at the end?

Comment: No, because `@books` is not defined yet. Even if it was, `@books.all = params[:books]` would call an `#all=` setter method which likely doesn't exist.

Comment: Fixed with @books = Book.all in my add method! I now know why it was not working. It could not find it in the sign in method.

Answer (score 4):

`Book#add` is calling an undefined method.  `#add` is defined in `BooksController`, not `Book`.

Unfortunately, this is only one of several issues. Your code suggests an incomplete understanding of how Rails works, which is not atypical of someone just starting out.

I suggest you focus your Rails studies on:

- the HTTP request/response cycle
- instance variables, especially lifespan and scope in controllers
- CRUD methods (a basic Rails convention)
- MVC architecture and the relationship between controllers and models

Comment: Okay well as you know I am still getting my head around it. I will investigate these areas without a doubt. Thanks for your feedback!